# Безопасность при передаче параметра в адресной строке и атака "человек посередине"

Tags: php, безопасность, уязвимости

Есть сайт **service.com**, выступающий в качестве точки авторизации для **mydomain.com** и для аналогичных ему (все сайты работают на одном движке по принципу единой точки входа и сквозной авторизации Single Sign-On).

Прошу совета, насколько безопасна передача токена в адресной строке:

1. После авторизации на **service.com**, осуществляется редирект на **mydomain.com** `header('Location: http://' . mydomain.com?token="12345")`, где token - случайный код, используемый при устанавке куки для этого пользователя на сайте **mydomain.com**.
2. После установки куки и запуска сессии `session_start()`, делаем еще одну перезагрузку уже без токена `header('Location: http://' . mydomain.com)` . Причина - безопасность, необходимо убрать из адресной строки токен.

Вопрос по безопасности в пункте №1. Насколько уязвим такой подход к атаке "человек посередине" и перехвату токена? Можно ли технически встроить `evil.com?get_token` в цепочку `header('Location: http://' . mydomain.com?token="12345")` ?

Comment: От любого человека посередине защищает https, а если его нет, то кто угодно (посередине) может встроить что угодно куда угодно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не хотите делать GET запрос, тогда передавайте все в виде списка параметров для POST. Тогда и не потребуется делать еще одну перезагрузку.

Также стоит использовать SSL (HTTPS), если хотите защитить данные в момент передачи (как GET, так и POST-запросы передаются без HTTPS в открытом виде).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я использую редирект на сайт service.com (т.е. в точку авторизации) при первоначальном заходе на сайт mydomain.com только лишь для того, чтобы выяснить, авторизован ли я там. GET-значения используются при обратном редиректе (мне все равно нужно в итоге оказаться на mydomain.com). Разве я могу другим способом запросить значение куки с другого домена средствами PHP, тем более POST запросом ? Насколько мне известно, нет. Возможно, я в чём-то ошибаюсь, прошу подсказать, в чём. Я опасаюсь угона токена именно при обратном редиректе.

Comment: конечно, например передаете cookies в cURL-параметрах CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookies и CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookies. надо только указать CURLOPT_POST => true.

Comment: @118_64 здесь все просто. чтобы не было угона токена на клиенте (например, через вывод параметра токена в адресной строке) посылаете все только в POST-запросах. также для безопасности всю пересылку данных надо шифровать SSL (HTTPS), чтобы предотвратить угон токена непосредственно при передаче данных, плюс использование защищенных соединений сейчас вызывает больше доверия (зеленая строка в браузере и т.д.)

Comment: Правильно ли я вас понял? Находясь на сайте mydomain.com посредством cURL-запроса я могу прочитать (именно прочитать, а не получить и установить) куки, ранее установленные на service.com? Разве это возможно иначе, нежели посредством браузера? Извините, что переспрашиваю.

Comment: нет, можно прочитать куки на клиенте в ручном режиме (если другой человек зайдет в браузер и вручную посмотрит куки нужного ему сайта). либо подсмотреть параметр в адресной строке (если он выводится GET-запросом). cURL может передавать данные по защищенному каналу используя SSL, тогда стороннему человеку крайне проблематично что-либо получить (но и это не 100% безопасность, т.к. на сегодняшний день уже есть не один десяток методов и технологий, которые позволяют обойти шифрование).